# How to show text in UILabel as secured in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm using `UILabel` for displaying the year value which i select through `UIPickerView`. I want the year field to be secure. In `UITextfield` we will use `setSecureTextEntry`, do we have anything similar for `UILabel`?

Thanks

Comment: You can use UITextField too in this case with userInteraction disabled so user wont be able to do anything. I guess that is your purpose

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure I really understand your question, but assuming you want to display asterisks in place of text in the label, just get the length of the string you would normally display and replace the characters with asterisks:

```
NSString *myPickerValue = @"MyPickerValue";
self.myLabel.text = [@"" stringByPaddingToLength: [myPickerValue length] withString: @"*" startingAtIndex:0];
```

Comment: if you prefer to use the icon that Apple use for save entry you can press option + shit + 6 and the result is this symbol •••••

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you just display your UILabel with ******* in it? I don't understand why you need to make a label "secure" when you are in control of what is being displayed.